# Find and Replace to fix broken links

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA and learning a ton using these forums but I am stumped on how I should tackle this problem I am coming across.

The Problem:

I am setting up VBA for our workplace physical inventory that we do 1 time per quarter. I have so far got my code to create a new folder based on today's date, and then the code will copy and paste all the files and subfolders from the master folder into this newly created folder. The issue I am having is that the excel file we use for our physical inventory, is linked to various other excel workbooks (which can be found in the sub folders under the master folder), so when the code copies and pastes the files, the file paths change and break the links to the various workbooks. Ideally, I am just trying to get my code to find and replace the existing "master template" folder path, to the newly created folder path as mentioned above. That way, all that needs to be done is to click the button that creates the new physical inventory folder with the master templates, then it will find and replace all existing external paths, with the new folder path to enable the links to continue working. If one of you master excel wizards would be so kind to help a rookie out, I would greatly appreciate it. I am not at work now, but I can provide the VBA code I have created thus far tomorrow. I am also always open to new ideas as to how I can do this in a simpler manner if find and replace isn't necessary. I have tried to do fix links command and that doesn't work without having to go through each workbook and manually changing path locations.

Thank you once again for all your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if code is not needed, there is a free tool that I came across which removed all broken links in the Excel workbook:

https://youtu.be/FyCNWE3_YpY

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).